# Excel numberformatting

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, formatting

I'm trying to create a excel from a datagrid with wpf, however when I format a column to just text it still converts some columns to what I presume to be a date conversion.

```
Excel.Range rg1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3];
rg1.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "text";
```

This is how the conversion of the column is set, but this results in Excel still formatting some fields to a date-ish value... If you look at the column foutcode you'll see what I mean.

[image]

results in:

[image]

I think what happens is that it automatically recognizes the value and sees if it fits a date format while I'm telling it to handle as just regular text! So does anyone have any idea on how to get rid of that? because the data is unusable because of this small error. Maybe use a more specific format than just text? however I can't seem to figure out how.

Also Convert a lot of rows into excel takes some quite a bit of time (4-5s for 1000 rows). Is there a way to make it go faster? All help is really appreciated.

```
public void ExportToExcel(List<Fouten> data)
        {
            try
            {
                if (data.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Image
                    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls";
                    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File";
                    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Data rapport";

                    // If the User Clicks the Save Button then the Module gets executed otherwise it skips the scope
                    if ((bool)saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
                    {

                        Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                        if (xlApp != null)
                        {
                            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);




                            int rowCount = 1;

                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 1] = "Datum";
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = "Tijd";
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 3] = "Foutcode";
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 4] = "Omschrijving";
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 5] = "Module";
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 6] = "TreinId";

                            rowCount++;


                            Excel.Range rg = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2];
                            rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss.000";

                        Excel.Range rg1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3];
                        rg1.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "text";

                        foreach (Fouten item in data)
                        {
                            string[] moduleNaam = item.Module.Split('_');
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 1] = item.Datum;
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = item.Time.ToString();
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 3] = item.FoutCode;
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 4] = item.Omschrijving;
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 5] = moduleNaam[0].ToUpper();
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 6] = item.TreinId;

                            rowCount++;
                        }



                        xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();

                        // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()))
                        {
                            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                            xlWorkBook.Close(true);
                            xlApp.Quit();

                            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                            releaseObject(xlApp);

                            MessageBox.Show("Excel File Exported Successfully", "Export Engine");
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing to Export", "Export Engine");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) for Text is an *'at'* symbol (e.g. capital 2 or **@**), not the word Text.

```
rg1.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
```

More at [Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)s.